# main gui and newjdialog mixed up on netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe, matisse

I have created new java application on Netbeans by pressing create new project and it creates java package. This fully fine ! When I add new JFrame it creates and automatically MAIN METHOD  , after I am done with Matisse I mean putting some gui components , I want to add JDialog to that , I go on package  right click and create JDialog Form which also created MAIN METHOD as well so  itself. So both MAINS mixes up. this is confusing me all the time. My Aim is to create JMenuItem called new , when I click on it I want my JDialog to be appear and something like project creation dialog. Help please ! How to combine to different components in these situations ?

Regards

Comment: Just get rid of the `main` method in the `JDialog` form. You don't need it. You will of course be responsible for calling `setVisible` yourself though when instantiating the dialog from your frame class.

Comment: this so confusing always , do have some  examples !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "this so confusing always , do have some examples "

I'm not so sure what is so confusing. Your program should only have one launching class with a `main` method. Netbeans will create a `main` method for you in `JDialog` forms, so just delete the `main` method. The only `main` method you need is your main `JFrame` form.

You have your `JDialog` form

```
public class MyDialog extends javax.swing.JDialog {
    public MyDialog(final Frame parent, boolean modal) {
        super(parent, model);
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initiComponent() {
        ...
    }

    // delete the auto-generated main method
}
```

You have your JFrame form with `JMenuItem`. Add a listener to the `JmenuItem` to open the `MyDialog`

```
public class MyFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem1;

    public MyFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /* Auto-generated code */
    private void initComponents() {
        jMenuItem1 = new JMenuItem();
        jMenuItem1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
    }

    /* Auto-generated method */
    private jmenuItemActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        /* Your hand written code */
        MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog(MyFrame.this, true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

---

> " How to combine to different components in these situations ? "

What does that even *mean*?

---

**Side Note**

- I'd recommend going through [Swing Tutotials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) and learning to hand code before jumping in to GUI Builder tools.

Comment: I was about to delete my self as well the main but you know ,  I was asking my self that is it the correct way to do ?Actually I am not confused with swing I am confused with steps of developing application on netbeans! Thanks for clear explanation ! Please share the steps of developing application on netbeans